# WordPress update

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to disable WordPress default update and change it to a way that get their updates from my server I want to write it as a plugin and add it to my all WordPress sites.

So is it possible to change default WordPress update server to my own server?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/YahnisElsts/wp-update-server

I've found this works really well and easy to set up and use. There may be more up to date libraries however as this hasn't been updated in a while.